# Preg_replace with a part of string but in another format

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string with the format:

```
$string = 'First\Second\Third';
```

'First' and 'Second' are always the same but Third' is just and an example (can be anything but in with special character '\' between them).

I want to create a string like that:

```
$string = 'Second_Third';
```

I tried to use function **preg_replace** and this is my code:

```
preg_replace(Array('/^First\\\/', '/Second\\\[^\s]+/'), Array('', '/Second\_[^\s]+/'), $string);
```

I have no idea how to do this.

10x

Comment: Can you give some sample input and sample output? Your description is not clear to me.

Comment: Ex: string = 'First\Second\House'. The output should be string = 'Second_House'. The main idea is to remove first word before special character '\' and  the the other special character should be converted in '_'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$str = preg_replace('/.*?\\\\(Second)\\\\(.+)$/', '$1_$2');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU4lG6/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for `\` then you don't need a regular expression. You can do a regular character match. Using `list` and `explode` you can do it like so:

```
list($first, $second) = explode("\\", "First\\Second\\Third");
echo $first . "_" . $second;
```

Note that you need to escape `\` because it's the escape character :>

Comment: Thank you, i did that but i wanted to use regular expression.

Comment: Why would you use a chainsaw if a knife suffices?